# pagination with Laravel Vue Pagination and vue js 3

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, pagination, laravel-10

i´m trying to create table with dynamic pagination. When i select my pagination number, i´m doing petition to my API and in my query ->paginate($param) i receive my data to paginate. This params it´s received correctly, but my problem it´s that i can´t draw my links. For build this, i´m using this [library][1] and i haven´t got any warnings or problems in my console. My actual code is:

My form:

```
const links = ref({})

const resp = await axios.get(`/api/listingApi/getRegister/${param_search.value["parameter"]}/${param_search.value["value"]}`)
        registers.value =  resp.data.data
        links.value = resp.data.links

<nAsignedCalls :valor="registers" :links="links"/>
```

I´m getting this data from my API

```
links: {first: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519?page=1",…}
first: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519?page=1"
last: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519?page=6"
next: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519?page=2"
prev: null
meta: {current_page: 1, from: 1, last_page: 6,…}
current_page: 1
from: 1
last_page: 6
links: [{url: null, label: "&laquo; Previous", active: false},…]
path: "http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519"
per_page:30
to: 30
total: 160

  [1]: https://laravel-vue-pagination.org/guide/components/bootstrap-4.html#usage
```

My API:

```
return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('cp', '=', $value)->paginate($pagination));
```

In my child component:

```
links: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }

import { Bootstrap5Pagination } from 'laravel-vue-pagination';

<Bootstrap5Pagination
                :data="links"
                @pagination-change-page="getResults"
            />
```

i tryed with Bootstrap4Pagination also, i have same result.

Comment: It seems odd that you have 2 `links` in your return response

Comment: @aynber thanks for your response. yes. It´s from my object ```meta``` i´m not using it. but i shared with you all my response